# Error while converting to float

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a file using csv.DictReader

I have a field that is supposed to be an integer.if it is empty i will set it as `DEFAULT`
if it is an integer i do nothing.if it is not an integer i check  if it is a quoted integer`(like '1234')`.if so I will convert it to integer.Else an exception is raised.

it works as expected if its empty or it is an integer.Now if it is a quoted integer`(like '1234')` ,an exception is raised `integer invalid literal for float(): '1234'`.

it is not supposed to raise exception in this case.

I think it has something to do with the way DictReader reads the csv file.
Everyhting else is just fine.Please help

```
 if not line[key]:
    line[key]='DEFAULT'
 elif not isinstance(line[key], (int, long, float)) :                        
    try:
      line[key]=float(line[key])
    except Exception,e :
      print e
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `float()` should work just fine on strings. However, if all the numbers are integers, why not use `int()`.

Comment: By integer i meant numeric.sorry.Also aix's answer is correct.its just that I cannot accept an answer within 8 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the single quotes are part of your string:

```
In [7]: float("'1234'")
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): '1234'
```

If you remove them, things should work:

```
In [8]: float("'1234'".strip("'"))
Out[9]: 1234.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the smartest way, but if you want to make sure there are only digits in your string, you could just remove all non-digits.

```
>>> import string
>>> extract = lambda s, charset: "".join(c for c in s if c in charset)
>>> float( extract("'h0424.234\"foo", string.digits + ".") )
424.234
```

Answer (score 0):

If your literal is something like "'1234'" or '"1234"' and '1234' you can use replace before converting:

```
data = ["'1234'", '"1234"', '1234', '', 1234]
[float(str(a).replace("'","").replace('"','')) if str(a).strip() else 'DEFAULT' for a in data]
```